# Fetching data using Angular 5 HttpClient

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to load data from a rest endpoint using the HttpClient provided by Angular. The endpoint in question uses a token to authorize the user.

```
    getData() {
     if (this.token) {
        const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type':  'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer' + ' ' + this.token
       })
     };
     this.http.get('https://some url', httpOptions).subscribe((res) => {
       console.log(res);
     }, (error) => {
       console.log(error);
     });
     } else {
       this.empty_token = true;
     }
   }
```

I get the following error while trying to do that: 
**Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401.**

However, the same code works for a some demo url that works on **"http"** and not for **"https"**.

I tried using the same by making a request using Postman or any other RestClient for that matter and it works fine.

Comment: `401` stand for `Unauthorized`. So your token should be invalid.

Comment: The same token works via postman.

Comment: The token has certainly expired. Though, you should take a look to the `http` specification: `401` means `Unauthorized`. So something is wrong in the authentication process.

Comment: I know what '401' stands for. And, I have tried adding multiple tokens.

Answer (score 0):

If the calling url is http it is normal that it does not work.
This could help you [https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer](http://If%20the%20calling%20url%20is%20http%20it%20is%20normal%20that%20it%20does%20not%20work.%20This%20could%20help%20you%20https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer)

Or try this

```
private httpOptions = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token});
```

Comment: The calling url is https

Comment: Try this code `private httpOptions = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token});`

Answer (score 0):

you should add

```
"proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/v1",
      "proxyUrl": "'https://some url'"
    }
```

to your project .

you can look to this link https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/wiki/Add-a-Proxy-to-browsersync