# Postman/Rest Client works but Pre flight Authentication error via angular application

Tags: angular, rest

I am trying to get data from an **https** endpoint in an Angular 5 application. It requires Authentication token which is added to the HttpHeaders and I  am using HttpClient component for making the get request.

```
   const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': 'Bearer' + ' ' + this.token,
                                    'Content-Type':  'application/json'});
   this.http.get('https://some url', {
    headers : headers
   }).subscribe((res) => {
     console.log(res);
   }, (error) => {
     console.log(error);
   });
```

But I am getting the following error:

[image]
I even tried using CORS plugin but it does not works. **401** is an indicator for Authentication error but the same token works for Postman and other clients.

Could anyone possibly point me in the right direction ?

Comment: you asked the same question two days ago and let the thread die, so I would suggest that you look at the answers there again or I would suggest that you use a network monitoring tool like fiddler or wireshark and compare the postman call and your angular call and have a look for the differences and if you found them try to rebuild the postman call in your angular application

Comment: Maybe type of headers should be be "Object"?

Comment: I tried all the solutions from last post but those were already tried out by me. Maybe wireshark looks like a nice proposition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetching data using Angular 5 HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49129030/fetching-data-using-angular-5-httpclient)

Answer (score 0):

The cloud service was rejecting the options from the angular application somehow. The issue is resolved.

Comment: check if here you have your response https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Sep/26/ASPNET-Core-and-CORS-Gotchas#Checkthatitworks